# Folding functions in netbeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans

Is there a way of folding open functions in netbeans when editing javascript? I currently have this, but only in html.

Or is there a key combination to go to the end '}' when standing at the begin'{'?

I'm sorry for this difficult explanation but it's the best I can do.

thx

EDIT: seems like netbeans can't fold anonymous functions - like the ones I am using as parameter to a jquery-call. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tested: theres a `-`-symbol between the line-numbers and the code next to the     `function blah(){`-line - sounds like thats what you're looking for (i'm using netbeans 6.9.1, maybe older versions don't have this feature)

**EDIT:** here you can see:

[image: Screenshoz]

**EDIT2:** to you comment: seems like netbeans can't fold anonymous functions - like the ones you're using as parameter to your jquery-call.

Comment: Yes I have that too, but only for functions.
For instance when I'm using jquery: 
$(document).ready(function()    {

}
You can't fold this open.

Comment: Yes your answer is good for my first question. Thank you.
Unfortunately I don't have that much standalone functions. Most of them are defined inside an element such as the document ready function. And when this is the case you can't unfold... which is bothering me pretty much

Comment: please see my secound edit - it's a pity, but netbeans can't do this (maybe theres an addon for this, i don't know)

Comment: Oke thanks, worked around it by putting an initfunction in the documentready so that one is foldable.